# How can I use cypher query to return the count of all the elements in one array?

Tags: arrays, neo4j, return-value, cypher, graph-databases

How can I count all the elements in one array with Neo4j cypher query?

For example, if I have a relationship like

> (a)-[:REL{type:[‘A’,’B’]}]->(b)

What’s the cypher query that I need to obtain the count of the elements of the attribute *type*? 
I would obtain something like

> count_of_elem: 2

I tried the function *count*

> MATCH (a)-[rel:REL]->(b) RETURN count(rel.type)

but it didn't return the correct value

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need the `length` function:

```
MATCH (a)-[rel:REL]->(b) RETURN length(rel.type)
```